# How to get a facebook closed group posts using facebook SDK for .NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

i am new to facebook API , i read this article:

http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/

Which says that we can get an access token dedicated to a certain user , but authenticating this user in our ASP.NET website through a facebook SDK for javascript authentication dialog, and we can then save the access token for making our queries.

my question is , does this mean that i can get the posts of a closed group in which the user is a member of? and how to do so?

thanks in advance

Comment: please take your time to go through the official docs before asking: https://developers.facebook.com/docs - if you still can´t figure it out on your own, describe exactly what you have tried so far and where you have failed.

Comment: my friend , believe me i did what you tell me to do..
i want my website to access a closed group posts, but this requires user-groups permission, a permission that facebook doesn't grant for public apps. i am asking if there is a work around

Comment: well, that´s a whole different story. in your question you only ask how to to so, not that your problem is with getting user_groups approved. anyway, that makes it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, your problem is with getting user_groups approved. As you found out already, that´s not possible: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_groups

The only way to get access to the group feed is by using user_groups, but you don´t need to go through the review process for users with a role in the App. So you CAN use user_groups with an App Admin/Developer/Tester, but you can´t create a public App with it.

Access to the group feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed

Comment: i need your help please,
i added a js sdk to my page to get the access token via a dialog box in which i enter my email and password. but the access token doesn't allow me to reach the posts of the closed group.
when i replace it with the access token which is auto generated in the API Explorer it works fine, but the programmatically gained one doesn't seem to be similar..
do you know why?

Comment: debug the token in the debugger and see if user_groups is in there correctly

Comment: thanks, it really worked for me.
but i need you ask you for a piece of advice, in order to know if i can continue with my graduation project idea or change it.
can i get your email or any other way of communication to describe my idea to you?

Comment: i am afraid i can´t offer help outside of the limited bounds of stackoverflow. too busy for extended help that is unpaid ;) - but you could just post it in the offical facebook developers group on facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: Ah ok, i understand the unpaid issue ;)
let me describe everything in few words,
i need to build a website for archiving and indexing the posts of my faculty closed group. The visitor to the site must see the latest posts of the closed group classified in the appropriate categories. i was planning to store them in a database.
giving the fact the "user_groups" permission is not available. my question is, can i continue with my idea? maybe by storing a developer email and password to use for fetching posts.
i also need a push notification mechanism to be notified by new posts. thanks in advance

Comment: it is possible, but you would need to use an extended user token

Comment: but facebook doesn't allow any type of storing login information. so hard coding the developer login details to login by the machine seems to be fuzzy :D

Comment: of course you should NEVER EVER store login details. i said extended user token, read the docs about user login and tokens. you don´t store passwords and whatnot for those.

Comment: please go to the facebook dev group on facebook for further questions, stackoverflow comments are not meant for those kind of discussions.

Comment: ok, thanks for all the help :) it was really valuable to me although it was unpaid ;)